# path based configuration in GCP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, microservices

I'm working on sort of prototype project. I have two **micro services** hosted on separate server with different tech stack. Here are some of the endpoints of it

```
1 User management
    -- /users
    -- /user/:id
    -- /user/roles
2 Other operations (e.g. managing a book, book details)
    -- /books
    -- /book/:id
    -- /book/:id/history
```

I'm using GCP for hosting my apps. I have one load balancer pointing to above **backend services**. I'm trying to use *Host and path rules* to use both services and it looks like below screenshot.
[image]

I would like to access my User management micro service as

```
dns/user-manager/users
dns/user-manager/user/:id
dns/user-manager/user/roles
```

and other micro service as

```
dns/book-manager/books
dns/book-manager/book/:id
dns/book-manager/book/:id/history
```

but it looks like, it just forwarding above url to particular service directly, so I'm getting 404. And I don't want to add all my routes to load balancer path settings as it will be difficult to maintain. Looking forward to hear some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding the hostname manually instead of using the ´*´? As I can see from the issue description, that you are using the host rule ´*´ instead of a specific host. See the [attached document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/url-map#adding_a_host_rule) for more details on it.

Comment: @Nur Yup, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want inbound requests to /user-manager/SUB/PATH to be forwarded to user-service and re-written to /SUB/PATH. It sounds like you have got the forwarding to work, but not the rewriting.

Google HTTP/S LB can't do the re-writing for you. You will have to add a reverse-proxy between GCLB and your microservice to rewrite the URLs. For example [nginx can do this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/).

Comment: Thanks! That's one way to do it. I'm thinking that is there any other way to do it just by Load-balancer.

Comment: I'm sad GLB can't do this for you.  It's an extremely common need.

Comment: Google now offers this feature: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management

Answer (score 0):

Google now offers [URL rewriting](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management#url-rewrite) which can achieve this.

Comment: I read this, but I don't understand - does Google have the ability to rewrite `website.com/one/two/three` to be `website.com/two/three`?